# How to sort output from Data::Printer?

Tags: perl, printing

I'm attempting to sort output from [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer) and having no luck.
I would like to sort numerically by value, instead of alphabetically by key (which is default).

inspired by [How do you sort the output of Data::Dumper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7466825/how-do-you-sort-the-output-of-datadumper) I'm guessing that Data::Printer's `sort_methods` works similarly to Data::Dumper's `Sortkeys`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use autodie ':default';
use DDP {output => 'STDOUT', show_memsize => 1};

my %h = (
    'a' => 0,
    'b' => 7,
    'c' => 5
);
p %h, sort_methods => sub { sort {$_[0]->{$b} <=> $_[0]->{$a}} keys %{$_[0]} };
```

but this prints out

```
{
    a   0,
    b   7,
    c   5
} (425B)
```

but the order should be `b`, `c`, and then `a`.
Curiously, there is no error message.

How can I sort the output of Data::Printer numerically by hash value?

Comment: Re "*I'm guessing that Data::Printer's `sort_method` works similarly to Data::Dumper's `Sortkeys`*", Where do you see `sort_method`?

Comment: @ikegami that's a typo, I corrected to `sort_methods` which does appear in https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer the hash still prints in the wrong order, however

Comment: You're not dumping an object, so `sort_methods` doesn't apply. And if it did, "*this option will order them alphabetically*"

Comment: The `sort_methods` has nothing to do with sorting actual data.  It's about how to show methods etc

Comment: Looks like you'd have to dig into filters, via [Data::Printer::Filter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer::Filter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not dumping an object, so [`sort_methods`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer::Object#sort_methods) doesn't apply. And if it did, "*this option will order them alphabetically*".

There is a [`sort_keys`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer::Object#sort_keys) option for hashes, but it determines "*Whether to sort keys when printing the contents of a hash*". It defaults to `1`, and there's no mention of a means to set the order. A test confirms that providing a sub doesn't provide a means to provide a sort order.

```
$ perl -e'use DDP; p {a=>5}->%*, sort_keys => sub { };'
[Data::Printer] 'sort_keys' property must be a scalar, not a reference to CODE at -e line 1.
```